# BO Webi - Looking to Calculate an Average Time for a Group of Orders

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to group orders together into buckets and calculate the average turnaround time for each. I am currently getting a #MULTIVALUE error on my table. Any suggestions would be a big help.

**Main Query**

[image]

**Lab Orders**

```
=If [Primary Orderable Item Mnemonic] InList ("Complete Blood Count w/Diff Auto";"Complete Blood Count w/o Diff";"Prothrombin Time w/INR";"PTT";"APTT";"Partial Thromboplastin Time") Then "Hematology" ElseIf [Primary Orderable Item Mnemonic] InList ("CMP";"Comprehensive Metabolic Profile";"BNP";"Creatinine") Then "Chemistry" Else "Other"
```

**Time Diff (Order to Completed)**

```
=TimeBetween([Order Date & Time];[Completed Date & Time];MinutePeriod)
```

**Order to Completed (MM)**

```
=If [Time Diff (Order to Completed)] >= 0 And Not(IsNull([Order Date & Time])) Then [Time Diff (Order to Completed)]
```

I'm trying to create a summary like this to display the average turnaround time (order to completed) for each group

[image]

=Average([Order to Completed (MM)])

Comment: I would recommend posting your question [here](https://bobj-board.org/). Provide sample data if you can.